# How do I find position of peak from Gaussian curve fitted data?

Tags: python, gaussian

So I've fitted the data below to a Gaussian curve with the code shown. How would I now find the x value of the peak? I've included everything to try be completely clear but yeah

```
import scipy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

x = sp.array([ 100.,  101.,  102.,  103.,  
104.,  105.,  106.,  107.,  108.,
    109.,  110.,  111.,  112.,  113.,  114.,  
115.,  116.,  117.,
    118.,  119.,  120.,  121.,  122.,  123.,  
124.,  125.,  126.,
    127.,  128.,  129.,  130.,  131.,  132.,  
133.,  134.,  135.,
    136.,  137.,  138.,  139.,  140.,  141.,  
142.,  143.,  144.,
    145.,  146.,  147.,  148.,  149.])
y = sp.array([ 49.62351587,  53.28471702,  
70.91469338,  59.347993  ,
    68.14021339,  47.96831052,  46.27111237,  
47.75670421,
    54.27684285,  49.79369344,  41.06072665,  
43.95823631,
    47.32189537,  57.59658829,  45.18881389,  
56.58866369,
    50.1240723 ,  42.6683265 ,  41.92068127,  
25.85132307,
    46.60808952,  38.07772697,  56.7941344 ,  
72.65808868,
    54.94790233,  84.97532661,  82.91663574,  
54.97400141,
    33.05466879,  31.07916615,  30.20075973,  
23.87661428,
    21.81024528,  28.83273888,  17.92903416,  
27.57351836,
    25.05685919,  27.4866161 ,  31.13142432,  
20.26710321,
    16.80327091,  14.1787744 ,  20.52320243,  
22.65700337,
    16.23164708,  11.78551076,  15.21441115,  
12.58749491,
    12.88956241,   6.24572757])

def fit_func(x,a,mu,sig,m,c):
    gaus = a*sp.exp(-(x-mu)**2/(2*sig**2))
    line = m*x+c
    return gaus + line

initial_guess=[10,120,10,-2,100]


po,po_cov=sp.optimize.curve_fit(fit_func,x,y,initial_guess)

plt.plot(x,fit_func(x,po[0],po[1],po[2],po[3],po[4]),label='Fit results')
plt.errorbar(x, y, fmt='o',capsize=2)

plt.show()
```

asdfghjkhgfdsdhjdsjsjdasdfjklasdfgkkdsasfgjkjdsdfgjldsdgklkdsdfgjkjdsasdfjklkjsdgklkjhgfdsdghjklkjhgfdsdjkjdsdghjkkjhgfdsdhjklkjgfdsaghjkjhfdsasfghhjklkdsasdghjklkdsdfghjkjdsasdgjklkdsasdghj